# A Write Only Database made for Event Sourcing?

Tags: database, activerecord, event-sourcing

Everyone is familiar with active record databases, where you write and then modify records to suit the times.

Less popular, but no less cool, is Event Sourcing, wherein *only* new records are written, and old ones are never modified.

Is there a database that was designed with this in mind? I imagine that, compared to a database that must also account for edit and deleting, the performance gains could be massive.

Answer (score 8):

There are! In general, anything that can function as a log can work as an event sourcing store, so your options are huge. Personally I've used:

1. [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/): Very useful for event sourcing. You can store events as topics. Kafka offers incredible escalability and performance
2. [EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/): A database created specifically for event sourcing, it allows you to store data readonly and offers extremely fast performance.

Comment: There are limitations around the number of topics you can create in Kafka so I'd be wary of this before using it for event sourcing